# Replacing text with Gradle

Tags: gradle

**Problem**

Received error because gradle can not read "\" or "-". If I change those values to "a","b" it works. How can I over ride this?

```
 ant.replaceregexp(match:'\', replace:'-', flags:'g', byline:true) {
 fileset(dir: project.'ws.dir', includes: 'warname.txt')
 }
```

[image: Image posted from comment below]

Comment: Try prepending them with \, like '\\'.

Comment: I did, the build was successful but it did not replace anything. Posted image of the error

Comment: Then try putting '\\\\' instead of '\'

Comment: Thank you it worked!!! I had multiple files of warname.txt was opening the wrong file.

Comment: Good. For reference, you can check whether your regex is valid at http://www.regexplanet.com/